# Problem with Offset Property on RTL mode in Vuetify framework

Tags: vue.js, offset, vuetify.js

I use vuecli3 and vuetify,
the  problem is offset in RTL have margin-left instead of right.
Also
i config properly my vuetify.js file and html lang direction too.

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'md',
  rtl: true,
});
```

Also i tried to add  these line to main.styl file

```
grid-offset-rtl()
  for $size in $grid-breakpoints
      for n in (0..$grid-columns)
        &.offset-{$size}{n}
          margin-left: 0
          margin-right: (n / $grid-columns * 100)%

rtl(grid-offset-rtl, "flex")
```

but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

just update Vueitfy package using npm, it is [fixed](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6317) now!

```
npm update vuetify
```

Comment: This question was asked a year ago when a version of the framework was 1.
When the issue was open.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that after I posted the answer and kept it like that so others can notice that (sometimes people get Vuetify (outdated version) out of the box with some starter kits or templates)

Answer (score 0):

I simply solved that by using conditional props

```
<v-col :offset-lg="isRtl ? 2 : 0" lg="5">
```

**isRtl** is computed property that checks for rtl mode:

```
isRtl() {
  return this.$vuetify.rtl;
}
```